# Who interrupts my thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, interrupted-exception

I understand what an InterruptedException does and why it is thrown. However in my application I get it when waiting for `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` on a thread that is only known by my application, and my application never calls `Thread.interrupt()` on any thread, also it never passes the reference of the thread on to anyone.

So my question is: Who interrupts my thread?

Is there any way to tell? Is there a reason why the InterruptedException doesn't contain the name of the Thread that requests the interrupt?

I read that it could be a framework or library that does this, we use the following, but I can't think of reason for them to interrupt my thread:

- Hibernate
- Spring
- Log4J
- Mysql connector

Comment: I think you mean "Who *DARES* interrupt my thread?"

Comment: +1 - Are you doing Thread#join ? it throws InterruptedException.

Comment: Indeed Scott, I would prefer my threads to be not interruptable (because I don't want to comply to the request anyway).
We don't do Thread#join ourselves, but I could imagine that invokeAndWait uses such a mechanism. However, would Thead#join invoke an interrupt on another thread? Also I'm pretty sure that noone waits for my thread to complete (as it is will never).

Comment: did Thread.dumpStacktrace() doesn't help ???

Comment: The current thread isn't the one doing the interrupt, so the dumpStackTrace shouldn't give me the information I need. The stacktrace from the exception shows it happens in Object.wait()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If possible, you could extend `Thread` and overwrite the `interrupt()` method for this thread to print a stacktrace or throw an unsupported operation exception.

You could also use the extended `Thread` class to store a reference to the interrupting thread and read it once you catch the interrupted exception.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you want to know who is doing something, attach a debugger, put a breakpoint, and there you go. No need for guessing if you can reproduce it!

In this case, you can put a breakpoint at `Thread.interrupt()`. If there are other threads that are being interrupted too (so you have "false positive" hits on the breakpoint), you could add a breakpoint condition (most IDE's allow you to do that easily), for example by checking the name of the thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is something strange here.

From the javadoc of [invokeAndWait](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)), an `InterruptedException` is thrown

> if we're interrupted while waiting for the event dispatching thread to finish excecuting doRun.run()

Have you tried to see if the code executed in the EDT sends any exception ? Or do the code in that EDT tries to modify some of this thread's variables (I know this term is not "orthodox" in java language, but I hope you see what I mean : any code implying synchronized, wait, join, ...

Comment: If the Runnable we are waiting for throws an exception it should give an InvocationTargetException, which isn't the case. It is possible that our threads has a lock while waiting, could that cause it? I'm sure we don't have a deadlock. The thread we wait for creates a dialog that we use in the waiting thread.